# Software to display 3d voxel video

Tags: graphics, 3d, data-visualization

I'm looking for a library similar to D3 or matplotlib but meant for 3-dimensional objects. My ultimate goal is to visualize an animated voxel object, along with interactions like slicing, boundary visualization, and a timeline.

There are various graphical rendering libraries this can be made with, but I'm wondering if there is already a library for visualization and manipulation of 3D voxel-based objects, such as images in medical science. I've aware of graphical rendering software like OpenGL, but to avoid reinventing the wheel, I'm hoping to find more feature-rich software.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern engines (Godot, Unreal, Unity, Lumberyard) are free to use and have built in voxelization algorithms. They are not as configurable as doing it on OpenGL but it might be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: According to the stack overflow guidelines [1], questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic. Since my question pertains to software used for data visualization, I claim it meets this criterion. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You gave examples of rendering engines, but I'm looking for data visualization utilities, similar to matplotlib for 3d. I could of course create such a tool, but my question is asking if any exists already. Thank you.

Comment: It is off topic:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319285/why-wont-stack-exchange-reconsider-the-recommend-or-find-a-tool-off-topic-tag. Three people have tried to close this question as off topic, which is enough usually. But the bounty prevents the question from being closed.

Comment: That being said. The fact you didn't like my answer is exactly the reason why these kinds of questions are off topic for this site. Rendering engines are also data visualization tools. They are often used to do things less powerful tools like Matlab and company cannot. And they have the technology you are looking for and it would take at most a day to get the visualization going. However it seems you don't consider that good enough.

Comment: In other words, this answer meets the criteria to your question but you don't like it out of a matter of opinion. And it's likely to happen to any other suggestions that don't one to one meet whatever you have in mind.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but I explicitly said I'm not looking for a rendering engine in the question. I appreciate the answer, but you're essentially saying "code it yourself," which is what I'm trying not to do. What I'm asking is more of a tool recommendation than a software recommendation, since I'm still hoping for a programmatical interface. I'm sorry this wasn't more clear to start off with. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Three.js". The library is very good for all sorts of 3d modeling in the web-environment. Look here: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-voxel-geometry.html

The site has much content specifically for voxel objects. I don´t know how high the model-resolution is supposed to be but you can use the library for sure in medical science.

The best way to have Voxel models loaded into a Three.js scene is to export .obj files. There is currently no reliable library for loading .vox files, but exporting .obj files is very easy.

Three.js is a very dedicated library and gets extended very well and i plan to start the first projects with it myself.